# Displaying data from JDBC into a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I've followed some previous advice on this site about displaying database information in tables, however mine still won't work. I have a generated Netbeans Dialog with a table named mainTable, I am setting the Model to a ResultSet that has been taken from the MySql.

**EDIT the entire class:**

```
import swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class AddressBookImpl extends AddressBookGui implements ActionListener {
final static AddressBookImpl impl = new AddressBookImpl();
DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
AddressBookGui gui = new AddressBookGui();



public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() { impl.startGUI(); }});
}

public void startGUI(){
    gui.main(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setTitle("Address Book");
    listeners();
    refreshTable();
}

public DefaultTableModel refreshTable() {
    try{

        DatabaseImpl dbimpl = new DatabaseImpl();
        dbimpl.refreshDatabase();
        ResultSet refreshResult = dbimpl.refreshResult;
        ResultSetMetaData meta = refreshResult.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = meta.getColumnCount();

        while (refreshResult.next()) 
        {
            Object[] rowData = new Object[numberOfColumns];

            for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; ++i)
            {
                rowData[i] = refreshResult.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            defaultTableModel.addRow(rowData);
        }
        this.defaultTableModel = defaultTableModel;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    gui.mainTable.setModel(defaultTableModel);
    return defaultTableModel;
}


public void listeners() {
    quitFileMenuBar.addActionListener(this);
    addButton.addActionListener(this);
    refreshButton.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) 
    {
        this.dispose();
    }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Add"))
    {
        // Add a new address to the DB
    }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("About"))
    {

    }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Refresh"))
    {
        refreshTable();
        System.out.println("Refreshing........");
    }
}
}
```

And the DatabaseImpl class:

```
protected ResultSet refreshDatabase() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connection is created to " + url);

        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        String selectAllQuery = "Select * from " + table + ";";

        ResultSet refreshResult = statement.executeQuery(selectAllQuery);
//          con.close();
        this.refreshResult = refreshResult;
        return refreshResult;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return refreshResult;
}
```

However this just shows a blank area where the table should be, any help?

The GUI class is a bog standard netbeans generated class.

Comment: Your code needs some refactorings... Is `AdderssBookGui` the dialog where the table is shown? Why are you disposing it directly after setting the `TableModel`? Or gets the `TableModel` set by the caller of this method (because you are returning the TableModel)?

Comment: AddressBookGui is the dialog yes, I removed the dispose and that still doesn't work, I was trying to add the TableModel straight into the AddressBookGui class, however that meant calling this method, and as this extends that class it got stuck in a loop and gave me a Stack Overflow Error.

Comment: That is connecting to the DB, getting the ResultSet Works fine, and rowData holds the information that was in the DB, it's just not applying to the JTable.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Where is there code for setting the GUI visible, i.e., `setVisible(true)`? Why does AddressBookImpl extend AddressBookGui? What is the purpose of `gui.main(null);`? Your use of inheritance here looks problematic, and likely you should not be using this inheritance.

Comment: Is the `main(...)` method of gui a public static main method that creates a new GUI instance and sets it visible? I think I'm smelling the problem! I'm pretty sure of myself now. Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're passing the TableModel into the wrong JTable, into one that is not being held by the currently visualized AddressBookGui instance. This won't work (as you're finding out) since setting the JTable of a newly created AddressBookGui instance will have absolutely no effect on the visualized object as while they are instances of the same class, they are independent of each other. The solution is to pass this model into the JTable that is held by the actually visualized AddressBookGui instance. Note a bad solution is to use static fields. Just don't do this.

**Edit**
I think that your problem is with a convoluted misuse of inheritance and again of setting the model of a non-visualized JTable. I suspect that your line of code `gui.main(null)` calls a static main method that creates and displays an AddressBookGui instance, and that this guy holds your JFrame. If so, then again this AddressBookGui instance that it is displaying is **not** the same as that held by the gui variable.

I suggest that you not have AddressBookImpl extend AddressBookGui, but rather have it simply hold a instance of AddressBookGui, and that you not call AddressBookGui's main method but rather have AddressBookImpl be responsible for displaying **its** AddressBookGui instance.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused, I removed the .setmodel(....); from the GUI class, and this method is called before that class is visualized anyway.

Comment: @MattC: then show us where you actually add the created model to the visualized JTable.

Comment: @MattC: I think I understand your problem and its solution. Please see edit to answer above.

Comment: So do I then just set mainTable.SetModel(defaultTableModel); ? 

I see the error of my ways now, that I was creating that same window several times before disposing the ones I was actually working on, not entirely sure why I didn't notice that.

Comment: @MattC: again you should not use inheritance here (are you clear on why?) and should not call the gui object's main method. You should create a gui object, yes, set its table model, *and you should **display** it*.

Comment: Yeah I'm clear on why, I have it now showing by creating the object, thanks a lot, I've been stuck on this issue for ages, I learnt a valuable lesson today. Cheers.

Comment: @MattC: glad you've got it figured out!